# Incredible 2 Sync Problem

Tags: usb-connection-mode, htc-sync-3.0, htc-droid-incredible-2

I've downloaded the HTC Sync software onto my PC in order to sync my new Incredible 2 with my Outlook, etc.  After plugging my phone into the PC with a USB cable, however, it tells me "No Device Connected."   How can I get the computer to recognize the phone?

Answer (score 2):

Check your phone if you have selected a default action when you plug in your phone. If memory serves, it connects in "Charge-only" mode by default, and pops a menu for selection. If you have already chosen a default action, go to `Settings->Connect to PC" and change the default. You'll need to choose "HTC sync" mode or somesuch.